# Pytthon / TXT: code to copy text after string

Tags: python, function

I have a txt file that will be different for different users, it looks something like:

```
NAME: Joe Bloggs
USERNAME: BLOGJOE
EMAIL: Joe.Bloggs@JB.com
PASSWORD: IAMJOE
```

I am trying to make an function where I can choose optional inputs for example, I want username and Password, then it will just return those 2 from the function, but have the ability to return all. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
def get_data(parameters):
    result = dict()
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            current_parameter, current_value = line.strip().split(':')
            if current_parameter in parameters:
                result[current_parameter] = current_value
    return result

data = get_data(['USERNAME', 'PASSWORD'])
print(data)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'USERNAME': ' BLOGJOE', 'PASSWORD': ' IAMJOE'}
```